# How can I determine the sector size in windows?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sector

How can I determine the **Physical Sector Size** (e.g. if i have an [Advanced Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) drive with 4,096 byte sectors rather than the legacy 512 byte sectors) in Windows 7?

I know that by clicking on a file and get properties we can find out the NTFS *Cluster Size*, but that's not the same as the hard-drive's *sector* size.

**Note**: We ask about Windows 7 because it (and Windows Vista SP1) understand the existence of 4096 Advanced Format hard drives.

Comment: I'm going to update this for Windows 10, since this is the first article that comes up in my search:  Use Powershell, "Get-Disk | Format-List"  (however, it doesn't show all of my disks...)

Comment: Better update for Windows 10, "Get-PhysicalDisk | select physicalsectorsize, friendlyname".  Shows all my physical disks and their sector size properly.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You want fsutil.  Make sure you run Command Prompt as Admin.

```
C:\Windows\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0xf4ca5d7cca5d3c54
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x00000000378fd7ff
Total Clusters :                  0x0000000006f1faff
Free Clusters  :                  0x00000000000e8821
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000000910
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :       512
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
Mft Valid Data Length :           0x00000000196c0000
Mft Start Lcn  :                  0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                  0x000000000097ffff
Mft Zone Start :                  0x000000000051f920
Mft Zone End   :                  0x000000000051f9a0
RM Identifier:        0652C3D3-7AA9-11DA-ACAC-C80AA9F2FF32
```

Comment: When property *Bytes Per Physical Sector: <Not Supported>* this means 512

Comment: @user2601995 Do you have a source for that?

Comment: What's 'FileRecord Segment' ? Is it the extra storage for files' metadata?

Answer (score 44):

Windows 10 update:

There is now a `sectorInfo` sub-command which may provide better information:

```
C:\>fsutil fsinfo sectorInfo C:

LogicalBytesPerSector :                                 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity :                    4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance :                  4096
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
Device Alignment :                                      Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device :                         Aligned (0x000)
Performs Normal Seeks
Trim Not Supported
```

Comment: Works on 2012 R2

Comment: Not available on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 31):

i wanted to expand on Chris Gessler's answer, and note that there is no known way to get the *Physical* sector of a drive using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), e.g. `wmic`.

Given that i have an Advanced Format drive (i.e. it uses 4,096 bytes per sector rather than 512):

```
C:\Windows\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0xa016d8a616d87eaa
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x00000000747057ff
Total Clusters :                  0x000000000e8e0aff
Free Clusters  :                  0x000000000e7b2813
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000000000
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :       4096
```

<strike>Neither WMI's `DiskDrive`:</strike>

```
wmic:root\cli>diskdrive
Availability  BytesPerSector  Capabilities  CapabilityDescriptions                                       Caption
              512             {3, 4, 10}    {"Random Access", "Supports Writing", "SMART Notification"}  ST1000DM003-9YN162 ATA Device
```

nor `Partition`:

```
wmic:root\cli>partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index
BlockSize  Index  Name                   StartingOffset
512        0      Disk #0, Partition #0  1048576
```

can report the underlying **physical sector size**. It makes sense when you realize they both report the sector size that Windows is **using**. It **is** 512 bytes per sector - the drive just happens to be different inside.

That's because only Windows 8 supports **use** of 4k sectors. Windows 7 understands that the drive might be 4k, and works to align it's 4k ***Clusters*** with the hard-drive's underlying 4k ***Sectors***.

### Update

`wmic diskdrive` now **does** show *physical* bytes per sector in **`Bytes per Sector`**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic
wmic:root\cli>diskdrive
Availability  BytesPerSector  Capabilities  CapabilityDescriptions                                       
              4096            {3, 4}        {"Random Access", "Supports Writing"}
```

While `wmic partition` continues to be wrong.

Windows 10.0.19041.804

Comment: **This answer is severely outdated.** These utilities now show the logical (emulated, almost always 512) and physical (real, almost always 4096) sector sizes. See the other answers.

Answer (score 15):

1. Run msinfo32 in command line that should popup a GUI window called
   "System Information"
2. In the left pane select "System Summary->Components->Storage->Disks". This should load info of all drives in the right pane
3. Find your desired drive and check the value for "Bytes/Sector". it should say "Bytes/Sector 4096"

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have it programmatically, you need to send `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX` and use `Geometry.BytesPerSector` from `DISK_GEOMETRY_EX` structure

Comment: That reports only the logical sector size. Getting a `STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR` struct from passing `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` to `DeviceIoControl` will get both the logical and physical sector sizes. The only shortcoming is that it doesn't work for external hard drisks - `DeviceIoControl` returns `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` (at least, I haven't found a way to make it work for external hard disks).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx#ECAA) from the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wmic partition get BlockSize, StartingOffset, Name, Index

BlockSize  Index  Name                   StartingOffset
512        0      Disk #0, Partition #0  32256
512        1      Disk #0, Partition #1  370195176960
```

The `BlockSize` is the sector size of the drive.

Comment: That `BlockSize` is the *logical* sector size, and not the *physical size* that `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:` reports. Source: i have a 4,096 AF drive that fsutil reports as 4096 and `BlockSize` reports as 512.

Comment: Second the above, this only reports logical sector size. `fsutil` reports correctly.

Answer (score 4):

**Powershell:**

```
$wql = "SELECT Label, Blocksize, Name FROM Win32_Volume WHERE FileSystem='NTFS'"
Get-WmiObject -Query $wql -ComputerName '.' | Select-Object Label, Blocksize, Name
```

**Output example:**

```
Label            Blocksize Name
-----            --------- ----
OSDisk                4096 C:\
Windows RE Tools      4096 \\?\Volume{b042c778-cd66-4381-9312-3f4311321675}\
PS C:\>
```

Comment: Explain this...  msinfo32 reports all as 512, this reports all as 4096, I KNOW I have both, as I can't set up a mirror, but I don't know which disk is which...  Also, this only shows the drive letter, not the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Recent powershell versions have a Get-Volume

```
Get-Volume  | Format-Table DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, AllocationUnitSize
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have it programmatically, you need to send `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` providing `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` with `PropertyId` set to `StorageAccessAlignmentProperty`. This gives both physical and logical sector sizes.

Note: this only works on Windows Vista and higher.