# Write partial data from MBR.bin to a sector in USB

Tags: windows, command-line, usb, dd

DD is a tool for linux which can Write partial data from MBR.bin to a sector in USB (instead of writing a whole sector). Now I need to do such thing in windows. There is a DD for windows, but it seems it will write a whole sector!

I need to write first 440 bytes of a mbr file to a usb stick. the code in linux is:

```
dd if=mbr.bin of=/dev/sd<X> bs=440 count=1
```

and in windows it will be:

```
dd bs=440 count=1 if=mbr.bin of=\\.\<x>:
```

where x is the volume letter. But in windows it will cause USB to be corrupted and usb need to be formatted. It seems it writes the whole data. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy a complete block!

e.g. for a 512 byte blocksize (512-440=72)

```
copy mbr.bin mbr.full
dd bs=1 if=\\.\<x>: skip=440 seek=440 of=mbr.full count=72
dd bs=512 if=mbr.full of=\\.\<x>: count=1
```

Comment: no it is not working :( Again it will make USB Corrupted and it must be formatted!

Comment: I need to write first 440 bytes of mbr.bin into sector 0 of USB derive. Just Executed your script and it worked normally, but it seems is writing the whole sector in USB and it will make USB corrupted.

Comment: Ofcourse it will write the whole sector: The first 440 bytes from mbr.bin, and the rest from the existing data, i.e. unchanged. For this to work, you must use the correct block size.

Comment: Can you guide how to get correct block size and make this script to work?

Comment: Yes: You use google to find out how to determine the block size of your USB, or you ask another question here. With the result, you come back to my answer.

Comment: What file system is your USB? Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465451/how-can-i-determine-the-sector-size-in-windows if it is NTFS.

Comment: Block Size of USB is 512, as it is used in the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77491/discussion-between-stranger-and-eugen-rieck).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you pass the parameters correctly? Maybe the win version expects it to be /bs=440. Just a guess. Can't you anyway just truncate the file to 440 bytes?